# Creating a regexp from string without quoting

Tags: ruby, regex, literals

My code will receive a parameter containing a string representation of a regular expression. It is probable that the strings would be like `"/whatever/"` with slashes at the beginning and end. Given a string,

```
str = "/^foo.*bar$/"
```

I would like to create a regular expression from that string.

When I do:

```
pat = Regexp.new(str)
# => /\/^foo.*bar$\//
pat.match "foolishrebar"
# => nil
```

all of the special characters are quoted. I have not figured out how not to quote the string.

When I create a pattern directly with `/pattern/`, it works fine.

```
pat = /^foo.*bar$/
pat.match "foolishrebar"
# => #<MatchData "foolishrebar">
```

Comment: As an aside, you almost always want `\A` and `\z` (beginning/ending of *string*) instead of `^` and `$` (beginning/ending of *line*) in Ruby.

Comment: If you really mean what you are asking for, then you can do `eval(str)`. But I am not posting this as an answer because I know that there are stupid people around who would downvote such an answer as soon as I post one.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `Regexp.new`, don't start and end your string with `/`. Just let `str = '^foo.*bar$'`. The only things being escaped are the beginning and ending slashes; the metacharacters are fine.

Comment: Also, I can use str.tr( '/', '') to remove any slashes from the string before passing it to Regexp.new.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = '^foo.*bar$'

r = /#{str}/
  #=> /^foo.*bar$/ 

"foolishly, the concrete guy didn't use rebar".match?(r)
  #=> true
```